# Test contents of return array in PHPSpec

Tags: testing, phpspec

Say I have this method of a RuleFactory:

```
public function makeFromArray($rules)
{
    $array = [];
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        $array[] = new Rule($rule[0], $rule[1]);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

I want to test that the return array contains Rule elements. Here is my test:

```
function it_should_create_multiple_rules_at_once()
{
    $rules = [
        ['required', 'Please provide your first name'],
        ['alpha', 'Please provide a valid first name']
    ];

    $this->makeFromArray($rules)->shouldHaveCount(2);
    $this->makeFromArray($rules)[0]->shouldBeInstanceOf('Rule');
    $this->makeFromArray($rules)[1]->shouldBeInstanceOf('Rule');
}
```

But this does not work, it throws an error in PHPSpec.

The strange thing is that I can do this just fine on other methods that return arrays, but for some reason I cannot do that here.

The error I get is this:

```
! it should create multiple rules at once
      method [array:2] not found
```

How do I test the contents of this return array, WITHOUT creating my own inline matcher?

Comment: If "alpha" means 'only allow alphabetic characters', then—even if it is unicode-aware—you're still excluding people like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Gaultier ; try to be more liberal in your validation of personal data.

Answer (score 2):

Your method accepts a single rule, not all of them. The spec should be:

```php
$this->makeFromArray($rules)->shouldHaveCount(2);
$this->makeFromArray($rules[0])[0]->shouldBeAnInstanceOf('Rule');
$this->makeFromArray($rules[1])[1]->shouldBeAnInstanceOf('Rule');
```

Or, to avoid multiple calls:

```php
$rules = $this->makeFromArray($rules);
$rules->shouldHaveCount(2);
$rules[0]->shouldBeAnInstanceOf('Rule');
$rules[1]->shouldBeAnInstanceOf('Rule');
```

Still, the most readable version would be the one leveraging a custom matcher:

```php
$rules->shouldHaveCount(2);
$rules->shouldContainOnlyInstancesOf('Rule');
```